# Where can I find the location of letsencrypt files in my AKS cluster? (Cert, Chain, FullChain, and Private Key)

Tags: lets-encrypt, azure-aks, cert-manager

I have a service (container) on AKS and a nginx-controller with cert-manager that automatically renews my certs.

I'm trying to find the exact location under the AKS File System where `/letsencrypt/live` is present which contain Cert, Chain, FullChain, Private Key.

Answer (score 0):

For the certificates in Kubernetes, you can take a look at [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/). And the description shows like this:

> The CA certificate bundle is automatically mounted into pods using the
>   default service account at the path
>   /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt. If you are not
>   using the default service account, ask a cluster administrator to
>   build a configmap containing the certificate bundle that you have
>   access to use.

As my understanding, it means the certificates are stored in the service account path and the path sees like `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` in default.

Comment: Thank you, but I got that from the `kubectl secrets` itself. What I need is something similar to letsencrypt type of cert generation.

Comment: @Vaikzs What document do you follow? Do you mean to renew the certificate?

Comment: I couldn't find the location (specific) to letsencrypt but I was able to find a solution without having to know the location of the certs. Thanks for the help Charles Xu.

Comment: @Vaikzs Can you explain your solution? And if the answer helpful?

Comment: Solution to my actual problem didn't require in "finding the location of the certs" in the first place.